# Replace dependency in IOC of Autofac in integrations tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm write integrations tests for existing project. The project using Autofac as IOC. 
I can't figure out how to replace service that was registered by Autofac.

I'm using .net core 3.1 and Autofac 4.9.4 and Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection 5.0.1
Part of service registered with standard .net core IOC, 
method looks like that

```
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    .....
    services.AddHangfireServer();
    services.TryAddTransient<IEfCoreEventDispatcher, EfCoreEventDispatcher>();
    .....
}
```

then register Autofac modules in other method which supposed to be call by autofac factory(not sure about that claim)

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    ....
    builder.RegisterModule<AutofacApplicationModule>();
    builder.RegisterType<MolliePaymentClientFactory>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
    ....
}
```

In the program.cs I specify custom factory for service provider according to autofac documentation.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder => webHostBuilder
            .UseSerilog()
            .UseStartup<Startup>());
```

In integrations test I create custom WebApplicationFactoty

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{


    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.Replace(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IEfCoreEventDispatcher), typeof(EfCoreEventDispatcherFake), ServiceLifetime.Transient));

            // Remove the app's AppDbContext registration.
            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>));

            if (descriptor != null)
                services.Remove(descriptor);

            // Add ApplicationDbContext using an in-memory database for testing.
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("testDb"));

            var hangfireMock = new Mock<IBackgroundJobClient>();
            services.Replace(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IBackgroundJobClient), hangfireMock.Object));
        });


    }
}
```

I can replace service that was registered by microsoft IOC, but can't replace service that was registered by autofac

When I try  to call

```
var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(IMolliePaymentClientFactory));
```

the result is null, it's not available yet at moment of calling "ConfigureServices" and i can't find a way to do that.

Is there anyone who can help me solve this?

Comment: ConfigureContainer happens after ConfigureServices finishes. You'd have to override Autofac registrations after ConfigureContainer runs. I'm in my phone and won't have time to come back so I can't get you links or examples, but maybe that unblocks you.

Comment: Yes. I know that. But unfortunately  there is bug that not allow to do this. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14907 , there is few workaround suggested in this topic they doesn't fit for me, they make structure of unit test really hard. Still looking for better solution. Currently I using suggested in this topic https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14907#issuecomment-589147555 by overriding configre container method of startup class.